# How to get latlngs from Flask to Javascript and add them as a polyline to Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, json, flask

I have a list filled with tuples like this: `[(-40.552939, -73.173871), (-40.556696, -73.170969), (-40.558869, -73.176589)]`
and I need to get it to my html file as latlngs and add a polyline with this data.

I've tried `json.dumps()` and `JSON.parse()` but they also didn't work, this is what I currently have:

app.py:

```py
@app.route("/rutas")
    def rutas():
        query1 = "SELECT latitud, longitud from Ruta WHERE num = '1a'"
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        resultado = cursor.execute(query1)
        resultado = resultado.fetchall()
        return render_template("rutas.html", ruta1a=resultado)
```

rutas.html:

```js
var latlngs = "{{ ruta1a|tojson|safe }}";
var polyline = L.polyline(latlngs, { color: 'red' }).addTo(map_init);
```